# Creating a Form that autofills itself

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I'm working on a "ticket" page, which its only a simple form that collects some info and saves a record. I need to have a select (combobox) from when I select something, some other inputs (textfileds) auto fill or populate themselfs. Very simple! When I select one option from this ComboBox the others Textfields "retrieve" the info related to that ComboBox and "print" it on the page without reloading.

I been working with PHP, MySQL, some Java and I'm soooo stuck :P

The only thing I achieved it that with Java I "pull" the value of the selection from the ComboBox to another TextField but I need at least 2 diferent values related to the first option:

In database look like this:

```
SOLUTION - CODE - COST
PAINT    - P990 - 3.20
GRIND    - G789 - 5.27
REPAIR   - RII8 - 89.2
```

So, I display all the "Labels" in the ComboBox, the related values, the CODE and the COST will need to auto fill another textfields every time I choose something different from the ComboBox :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript and detect when the combo box changes value then use javascript to do an http request (get or post), then php returns the information you requested and you populate the form.

ie:

```
<script>
//using javascript
$("#combobox").on("change", function(){
  $.post("process.php",{sel: $(this).val()}, function(result){
    $("#val1").val(result.val1);
    $("#val2").val(result.val2);
    $("#val3").val(result.val3);
    //...
  });
});
</script>
```

**process.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['sel'])) {
  $sel = $_POST['sel'];

  // do some processing

  echo json_encode(array(
    "val1" => "some value",
    "val2" => "some value 2",
    "val3" => "some value 3",
  ));
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Yoel! Thanks for helping out but your answer took me on another direction :( but I learned something from it :)